# Debugging the .NET WsdlImporter class without PDB symbols

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, pdb-files

I'm working on a project that uses the WsdlImporter class to set up a proxy for a WCF service. We're getting horrible performance (~40 seconds) on one particular function call:

`_contracts = wsdlImporter.ImportAllContracts`

This only imports two contracts with a total of 30 operations, so doesn't seem like it should take this long.

Unfortunately, the WsdlImporter class belongs to a namespace (System.ServiceModel.Description) that Microsoft hasn't released a PDB symbol file for. So I can't set breakpoints within the .NET framework code to debug.

I have two different questions:

1) Is anyone aware of specific performance issues with the WsdlImporter class or ImportAllContracts() method that might be slowing me down?

2) More generally, can anybody suggest a clever trick for debugging or breakpointing .NET framework classes that don't have their symbols released? One idea I had was to create a new class in my local project namespace, then copy in the source code from Microsoft's http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ site. However this particular method calls out to several other functions that are expecting parameters as native .NET objects, not my hacked local object, so this ran into a dead end.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Why are you not using a profiler to diagnose performance issues? If 40s of time is wasted it should be an easy spot with a debugger or a profiler simply by looking at the call stack which takes so long.

Comment: I've tried that, the profiler indicates the same function above (WsdlImporter.ImportAllContracts()) is causing the performance bottleneck. But it doesn't analyze any deeper than that. Without the PDB symbol file we can't trace what's actually going on in there, or which particular sub-call is taking so long.

Comment: Normally you will be able to see if it is spending 40s of CPU of it is waiting 40s for something. If it is CPU it should be quite obvious what is taking so long. If you use WPR as profiler you can see the code addresses which are hottest which can be checked with a memory dump of the process to see which part of the method was so expensive. With the Reflector addin you can also debug into methods with no source code which could help as well.